# How to make Picasa handle .MTS files (AVCHD Lite) correctly?

Tags: windows-7, picasa, mts

Picasa 3 does not recognize .MTS files correctly and does not handle playback.
It does copy the files from flash-ram to hard disc, but does not show them along with the images.

Comment: This link http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=19626 indicates that installing K-lite might solve the problem. Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the following two

1. http://www.free-codecs.com/FFDshow_download.htm
2. http://haali.su/mkv/

to make it work. Confirmed for me. No longer crashing.

Alternatively http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm will also work.

Found this info at http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/h9G_WOaldvw